# jquery not running in python using google app engine

Tags: jquery

I am a fresher in python. I want to run jquery datatable in python i have separate html file. My  tag is running in html output by using App Engine but i have implemented datatable with my html table but it is just showing  stuff not executing datatable function. I have included all css and jqueries. It is showing alert in javascript tag but not in $document.ready it means this function is not running. So obviously datatable will not bind with this table. Please help me! thanks a tonne in advance...

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
 @import "DataTables/media/css/demo_page.css";
 @import "DataTables/media/css/demo_table.css";
 @import "DataTables/media/css/demo_table_jui.css";
 @import "DataTables/development-bundle/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css";
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables/media/unit_testing/tests_onhold/1_dom/bJQueryUI.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
alert ("Entered in javascript...");

$(document).ready(function(){
alert("Got it...");
$("#display").dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI":true
});
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
<table id="display">
    {% for greeting in greetings %}
        {% if greeting.author %}
            <tr><td><b>{{greeting.author.nickname }}</b> wrote:</td>
        {% else %}
            An anonymous person wrote:
        {% endif %}
            <td><blockquote>{{ greeting.content|escape }}</blockquote></td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
<tr><td>
    <form action="/sign" method="post">
      <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
    </form>
</tr></td></table>

</body>
</html>
```

alright this is my code... now where i am wrong...

Comment: jQuery doesn't "run in python(/php/perl/ruby/...)" as it's a pure client-side library for Javascript.

So something is wrong with your HTML code. Without you showing the code we cannot help you though.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
alert ("Entered in javascript...");

$(document).ready(function(){
alert("Got it...");
$("#display").dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI":true
});
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
<table id="display">
 {% for greeting in greetings %}
  {% if greeting.author %}
   <tr><td><b>{{greeting.author.nickname }}</b> wrote:</td>
  {% else %}
   An anonymous person wrote:
  {% endif %}
   <td><blockquote>{{ greeting.content|escape }}</blockquote></td></tr>
 {% endfor %}
<tr><td>
</tr></td></table>

Comment: i have appended my html code now tell me where i am wrong..

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the wrong url to the jquery file. I copied your code. When I changed the jquery script line to the following, I got the second alert.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You seem to be confused about what runs on the client, and what runs on the server. Reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) should give you a better understanding.

I recommend that you use something like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to help you find **client side** problems. In this case, you would have easily seen that the url was wrong in then net tab of firebug.